# C++ range based forloop traversing a vector but cout only prints first item in the loop

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am doing the AOC challenege day 2, and I have written the below code to traverse an iterator holding the quiz input. The idea is to dump the input into the vector, go through the vector to parse it and do the challenge. I am using vectors for learning purposes,

But for cout in the for (i: arr) it is not working. they only print the first item and wont print anything else. I ran it through the debugger it is definetly traversing the entire vector but cout only prints this:

`startforward 8f`

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : hello.cpp
// Author      :
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================


// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("/home/user/eclipse-workspace/AOC2/puzzleinput/C2a_input.txt");
  vector< string > arr;

  cout << "start";



  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int i=0;

    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        arr.push_back(line);



        i++;

    }
    myfile.close();

  }

  else {cout << "Unable to open file";}
  //file is read, now we calculate hor and depth

  int horizontal = 0;
  int depth = 0;

  for (auto i : arr){
      cout << i;
      cout << i[0];
      cout << i[sizeof(i)-1];
      if (i[0]=='f') {
          horizontal += i[sizeof(i)-1];
      } //forward
      if (i[0]=='u') {
          depth -= i[sizeof(i)-1];
      } //up
      if (i[0]=='d') {
          depth += i[sizeof(i)-1];
      } //down



  }

  cout << depth*horizontal;





  return 0;
}
```

the quiz input is as follows:

```
forward 8
down 8
...etc
```

Comment: `sizeof(i)` is not the size of the string. You want `i.size()`.

Comment: @user17732522, sorry, let me check real quick.

Comment: @user17732522, sorry, my mistake. I mixed up. So, `i.size()` is the only way.

Comment: `sizeof(i)` gives the byte-size of the object instance. For your purpose (index/no. of characters) you need to use `i.size()`. PS: Sorry, for my previous mistake. I mixed up.